# x<<y>>z order of evaluation in C

Tags: c, evaluation

What is the order of evaluation in C in the case of `x<<y>>z` ? Is it `(x<<y)>>z` , because of the Left to Right associativity ?

**EDIT**
Need to know what the standards tell about it, and not guess what's going on by inspection for a particular compiler.

Comment: Have you tried it? What you got?

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: Tried here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx . But i was confused with the line: "Order of operations is not defined by the language"

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: Even if you try it, how do you know/prove that your compiler is standard compliant?

Comment: @VladLazarenko What's worse, it may be perfectly standard compliant and the expression invoked undefined or implementation defined behavior.

Comment: @delan: That was the question: what does the standard tells about it.

Comment: note: if you are unsure about the order, *always* use parentheses. even if you figure out what it does, the next developer is faced with the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Online C 2011 Draft Standard (N1570)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

```
6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators

Syntax

1     shift-expression:
          additive-expression
          shift-expression << additive-expression
          shift-expression >> additive-expression
```

The syntax indicates both operators are left-associative, as follows:

```
    x      <<       y         >>           z
    |               |         |            |
    +------ + ------+         |            |
            |                 |            |
            V                 |            V
      shift-expression        >>   additive-expression
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `>>` and `<<` are left associative and of the same precedence, so `x << y >> z` is equivalent to `(x << y) >> z`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right because the << and >> Operator have the [same precendence and are left-associative](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Answer (score 1):

Both `<<` and `>>` are on same level and their direction is left to right.

so it will be `(x<<y)>>z`

For more references..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Yep it is, but i think it's more secure to do in 2 steps, like `x<<y` then `y>>z` cause the compiler can interpret badly a `x<<y>>z`. I haven't used bitwise operations since a whole time but if i remember well it's what i said. I hope i've helped you.

Comment: Thank you for editing, didn't seen my mistakes. Sorry for the OP.

Comment: the compiler cannot interpret it badly (close to 0 chance for a bug, order of evaluation is a really fundamental thing)

Comment: I've seen that mistake too (don't know what went through my brain)